# Why mutable built-in objects cannot be hashable in Python? What is the benefit of this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I come from Java where even mutable objects can be "hashable".
And I am playing with Python 3.x these days just for fun.

Here is the definition of hashable in Python (from the Python glossary).

> hashable
>
> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable; mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are not. Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default. They all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is derived from their `id()`.

I read it and I am thinking... 
Still... Why didn't they make in Python even mutable objects hashable? E.g. using the same **default** hashing mechanism as for user-defined objects i.e. as described by the last 2 sentences above.

> Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default. They all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is derived from their id().

This feels somewhat weird... so user-defined mutable objects are hashable (via this default hashing mechanism) but built-in mutable objects are not hashable. Doesn't this just complicate things? I don't see what benefits it brings, could someone explain?

Comment: To hash a list, you would have to first hash everything in it; because it is mutable, any change to it should change the hash. To hash a tuple, it is sufficient to hash its `id()` because it can't be modified. Users would *generally* expect hashing a user-defined class to behave more like an immutable object (even though it is mutable) so that's what it does, although of course you can make it behave any way you like.

Comment: @kindall: Tuples are not hashed by `id`.

Comment: @kindall Hm... Who says that the hash value has to come from the values in the list? And that if you e.g. add a new value you have to rehash the list, get a new hash value, etc.. In other languages that's not how it is... this is my point. In other languages the hash value just comes from the id (or is the id itself, just like for user-defined mutable Python objects)... And OK... I just feel it makes things a bit too complicated in Python (especially for beginners... not for me). Anyway... thanks for all answers here, I will keep watching new answers which come in.

Comment: @peter.petrov: In Java, the language you're coming from, collection `hashCode` values *are* based on container contents. For example, [here are the List docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--). Anything else would be broken and/or useless, since `equals` is based on collection contents.

Comment: @peter.petrov Doesn't that mean you could have two different lists with the exact same contents and they hash to two different things? This makes semantics very confusing if you want to check if something like a `set` has a `list` in it. E.g. if you did `x = {[1]}`, then `[1] in x` would return `False`. It might be hard to say what is or is not confusing to a beginner, but broken semantics can't be good...

Comment: @user2357112 yes, exactly. To me, this is one case where Java is actually more willing to let you shoot yourself in the foot than Python is, by letting you put mutable objects that hash based on mutable state into HashMaps. Although, I suppose, the Python hashmap container is much more ubiquitous so perhaps that required more guardrails.

Comment: "by letting you put mutable objects that hash based on mutable state into HashMaps" Wow... I was assuming in Java they don't hash Lists based on mutable state but just based on id or something (as Python does for its mutable user-defined objects). This assumption was wrong... That's really weird (the Java way, I mean)... So I asked a question about Python here... but learnt (or refreshed) something about Java too. That is strange behavior in Java indeed. I don't like it either. Now the Python way indeed makes some more sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, mutable objects *can* be hashable, but it is generally not a good idea, because generally speaking, the *equality* is defined in terms of these mutable attributes, and this can lead to all sorts of crazy behavhior.

If built-in mutable objects are hashed based on identity, like the default hashing mechanism for user-defined objects, then their hash would be inconsistent with their equality. And that is *absolutely* a problem. However, user-defined objects by default compare and hash based on identity, so it isn't as bad of a situation, although, this set of affairs isn't very useful.

Note, if you implement `__eq__` in a user-defined class, the `__hash__` is set to `None`, making the class *unhashable*.

[So, from the Python 3 data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> User-defined classes have `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods by
>   default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with
>   themselves) and `x.__hash__()` returns an appropriate value such that
>   `x == y` implies both that `x is y` and `hash(x) == hash(y)`.
>
> **A class that overrides `__eq__()` and does not define `__hash__()` will have its `__hash__()` implicitly set to `None`**. When the
>   `__hash__()` method of a class is `None`, instances of the class will raise an appropriate TypeError when a program attempts to retrieve
>   their hash value, and will also be correctly identified as unhashable
>   when checking `isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Hashable)`.

Comment: "If built-in mutable objects are hashed based on identity, like the default hashing mechanism for user-defined objects, then their hash would be inconsistent with their equality. And that is absolutely a problem." Hm... That is a good point... that is a problem you say... but when viewed purely from computer science standpoint... that's a problem because of how equality is implemented.

Comment: E.g. to me (since I come from Java) lst1 == lst2 returning true (for 2 different lists with same values) seems strange too. So... OK... I guess it is just a very basic language design decision to question it (as I do here) but still... seems like it makes things a bit too complicated.

Comment: @peter.petrov in Python, `==` is equivalent to Java's `.equals`, whereas `==` in Java is equivalent to `is` in Python.

Comment: Yeah... that I know already... OK, well, thanks, I will think some more on all this.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating a hash value is like giving an identity to an object which simplify the comparison of objects. The comparison by hash value is generally faster than the comparison by value: for an object, you compare its attributes, for a collection, you compare its items, recursively…

If an object is mutable you need to calculate its hash value again after each changes. If this object was compared equal with another one, after a change it becomes unequal. So, mutable objects must be compared by value, not by hash. It’s a non-send to compare by hash values for mutable objects.

**Edit: Java HashCode**

Typically, hashCode() just returns the object's address in memory if you don't override it.

See the [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) about the `hashCode` function.

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by
>   class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This
>   is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the
>   object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming language.)

So, the Java `hashCode` function works the same as the default Python `__hash__` function.

In Java, if you use a mutable object in a `HashSet`, for instance, the `HashSet` isn’t working properly. Because the `hashCode` depends of the state of the object it can no longer be retrieved properly, so the check for containment fails.

Comment: Well... this is again taking a one-sided (Pythonic) view on the question. Quote: "If an object is mutable you need to calculate its hash value again after each changes" This statement is not true in general, it is true in Python.

Comment: @peter.petrov well, yes, *but you are asking about Python*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well... OK... yes and no... Think a bit more deeply, I think you see what I mean.

Comment: "So, the Java hashCode function works the same as the default Python __hash__ function." Yes, for user-defined objects - yes. That's the whole point of my question. Why didn't they make built-in immutable and user-defined immutable objects behave uniformly as far as hashing goes? Sounds somewhat unbalanced, asymmetrical this behavior. Never mind... I know... I have to ask whoever made the decision :) It's a deep/basic language design thing. I was just curious what the community will say. Thanks for your perspective anyway.

Comment: @peter.petrov because then *equality would be useless in Python*. When I ask if a list is `.equals` to another list in Java, do you expect it to work based on the elements of the list, or on the identity of the list? IIRC, `.hashCode` and `.equals` must be  consistent in Java, and the equivalent methods work the same in Python, `__hash__` and `__eq__` must be consistent.

Comment: @peter.petrov: Built-in classes and properly-implemented user-defined classes behave identically in this regard. There is no asymmetry.

Answer (score 1):

From reading other comments/answers, it seems like what you're not buying is that you have to change a hash of a mutable entity when it mutates, and that you can just hash by `id`, so I'll try to elaborate on this point.

To quote you:

> @kindall Hm... Who says that the hash value has to come from the values in the list? And that if you e.g. add a new value you have to rehash the list, get a new hash value, etc.. In other languages that's not how it is... this is my point. In other languages the hash value just comes from the id (or is the id itself, just like for user-defined mutable Python objects)... And OK... I just feel it makes things a bit too complicated in Python (especially for beginners... not for me).

This isn't exactly false (although I do not know what "other" languages you are referencing), you *could* do that, but there are some pretty dire consequences:

```
class HashableList(list):
    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)

x = HashableList([1,2,3])
y = HashableList([1,2,3])

our_set = {x}

print("Is x in our_set? ", x in our_set)
print("Is y in our_set? ", y in our_set)
print("Are x and y equal? ", x == y)
```

This (unexpectedly) outputs:

```
Is x in our_set?  True
Is y in our_set?  False <-- potentially confusing
Are x and y equal? True
```

This means that the hash is not consistent with equality, which is just downright confusing.

You might counter with "well, just hash by the contents then", but I think you already understand that if the contents change then you get other undesirable behavior (for example):

```
class HashableListByContents(list):
    def __hash__(self):
        return sum(hash(x) for x in self)

a = HashableListByContents([1,2,3])
b = HashableListByContents([1,2,3])

our_set = {a}

print('Is a in our_set? ', a in our_set)
print('Is b in our_set? ', b in our_set)
print('Are a and b equal? ', a == b)
```

This outputs:

```
Is a in our_set?  True
Is b in our_set?  True
Are a and b equal?  True
```

So far so good! But...

```
a.append(2)
print('Is a still in our set? ', a in our_set)
```

this outputs:

```
Is a still in our set?  False <-- potentially confusing
```

I am not a Python beginner, so I would not presume to know what would or would not confuse a Python beginner, but either way this *seems confusing to me* (at best). My two cents is that it's simply incorrect to hash mutable objects. I mean we have functional purists that claim mutable objects are just incorrect, period! Python won't stop you from doing any of what you described, because it would never force a paradigm like that, but it's really asking for trouble no matter what route you go down.

HTH!