# Why are mutable user-defined objects hashable, but not lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Instances of user-defined classes are mutable, but hashable i.e. we can make sets out of them or use them as keys for `dict`s.

Lists are mutable, but not hashable.  Why not?

From the [Python3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) circa 5 March 2021:

> Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by
> default.  They all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their
> hash value is derived from their id().

Why can't one apply the same logic to lists -- i.e. derive a list's hash value from its `id()`?  It can't be that the `id` of a list changes, can it?

This has implications on what can be converted to a set or what can be made a key in a dictionary.

Comment: On looking around further, this largely overlaps [Why mutable built-in objects cannot be hashable in Python? What is the benefit of this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56012884/364696). I'm hesitant to use my badge hammer to dupe to it, I'll leave that to others to make the call.

Comment: Read the rest of the question; it's asking about the difference between unhashable mutable built-ins (like `list`) and hashable mutable user-defined classes (which are hashable by default based on `id()`), much like this question is. The emphasis is different, but the underlying question is very similar.

Comment: @user650654 I've marked it as a duplicate, but no need to delete it; there is an upvoted answer here, and duplicated questions can make it easier for future readers to find an answer by searching.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer, while largely correct, overcomplicates things and gets pretty far into the weeds. The answer to the actual question ("Why are mutable user-defined objects hashable, but not lists?") is pretty simple. `list`s don't use their identity as a hash because it would require either:

1. `list`s to compare for equality based on identity (so `[1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]` would always be `False`, because they're different `list`s), or
2. `list`s would have to violate the hash invariant, which says that two objects that compare equal *must* have the same hash (or be unhashable)

Because neither outcome is desirable, the `list` class overrides `__eq__` (allowing `list`s to be compared lexicographically), but not `__hash__` (because it would have to base the hash on the contents to match the implementation of `__eq__`, but the contents can change, so it would not be safe to do so).

As for why objects *do* use their identity by default, that's open to argument. There are some minor advantages to being able to use simple `object`s as "handles", where whoever has a reference to the object can use it for look up in a `dict`. It's a pretty minor benefit though, and I suspect, were the language being designed from scratch, `__hash__` would be undefined by default, leaving it to class designers to provide a sane `__hash__` when appropriate, rather than silently allowing classes that define neither `__eq__` nor `__hash__` to be hashed.

Comment: What does "compared lexicographically" mean exactly?

Comment: @martineau: See [the Python tutorial section on comparing sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=lexicographic#comparing-sequences-and-other-types); basically, it compares the contents from left (index 0) to right (index `len(seq) - 1`). For equality, the order *mostly* doesn't matter (they're either all the same, they're not equal, though for incomparable types, an early out due to unequal elements earlier on might save you a `TypeError`), but the ordering matters for `<` and company, as the result is based on the first pair of elements to compare unequal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The two requirements are not obvious: why should one compare lists by id in the first place?  Your second rule ("two objects that compare equal must have the same hash") is incorrect--two lists (or any mutable) can compare as equal and yet are unhashable i.e. do not have the same hash.  I think [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) says it better, but is again not obvious: The hash() result should be consistent with equality. Objects that are equal should either have the same hash value, or be marked as unhashable.

Comment: @user650654: The second rule is for things which have a hash at all. If you can't come up with a hashing solution that preserves that invariant, it should not define a hash. You can describe it a number of ways, but the invariant only applies when there is a hash in the first place. For the "lists by id", that was in response to your proposal to derive the hash value from the `id()`; you could do that, but to preserve the hash invariant, equality would have to be defined in terms of the `id()` as well. Option #1 is adhering to the hash invariant by making `list` equality mostly useless.

Comment: I have removed my answer since it does not appear to add value.